# Java Stream - Backward reference to previous class

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Class
{
    private Long id;

    private String someValue;

    private List<SubClass> subclasses;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class SubClass
{
    private Long id;

    private String someSearchValue;
}
```

I need to find first `Class` and first `SubClass` where some value match to `SubClass.someSearchValue` field.

This is what did:

```
void someMethod(List<Class> classes){

    SubClass foundSubClass = classes.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> c.getSubclasses().stream())
        .filter(sc -> "someValueToSearch".equals(sc.getSomeSearchValue()))
        .findFirst().get();

    Class someClass = classes.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getSubclasses().stream().anyMatch(sc -> "someValueToSearch".equals(sc.getSomeSearchValue())))
        .findFirst().get();
}
```

As you see I have to use `filter` twice using this same condition `"someValueToSearch".equals(sc.getSomeSearchValue())` to find both object. Is there any possibility to find both objects using `filter` only once? I know the easiest way is to do it is putting a reference to `Class` in `Subclass`, but I can't do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try writing the same code with for-loops, from there you'll see quite fast what can be done with streams, and what can not. This intermediate step at least helps me when trying to do some logic with streams

Comment: True-to-intent stream usage can only yield you one result, while you need two. You can, of course, write a code with streams that would produce several results by using side-effects, but the main question is: why use streams at all? You can already see the shorfalls of that approach. Go with what @Lino suggested and don't use streams here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can assert that `foundSubClass` must definitely be a child `someClass` - the first one with `someValueToSearch` - so there are definitely efficiency gains to be had by reversing the order of the streams and only looking at `someClass` in the second search.

You can also tidy this up by using a method reference rather than defining the same lambda twice.

```
Class someClass = classes.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getSubclasses().stream().anyMatch(Test::search))
    .findFirst()
    .get();

SubClass foundSubClass = someClass.getSubclasses().stream()
    .filter(Test::search)
    .findFirst()
    .get();

//...

private static boolean search(SubClass subClass)
{
    return "someValueToSearch".equals(subClass.getSomeSearchValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an improvement which I actually did, but I wrapped `SubClass` in `Predicate` instead of using method reference.